# Grails domain class containing itself

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm trying to implement Subpage domain class in Grails and I would like to have Subpage with possibility of storing another Subpage. I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787120/grails-domain-class-relationship-to-itself) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201420/grails-table-that-links-to-itself?lq=1) post but none of these solutions seems to work for me.

My class looks like this:

```
class Subpage implements Comparable{

    String title
    Integer orderOfSubpage
    SortedSet subpageChild

    static hasMany = [component: Component, subpageChild: Subpage]
    static belongsTo = [domain: Domain, subpageParent: Subpage]

    static constraints = {
        orderOfSubpage nullable:false;
        subpageParent nullable:true;
        subpageChild nullable:true;
    }

        @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if (this.orderOfSubpage > o.orderOfSubpage) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.orderOfSubpage < o.orderOfSubpage) {
            return -1;
        }   
        return 0;
    }
}
```

According to the implementation, I was expecting Hibernate to create additional table with children, but I've looked into the database and the only one "mention" about Subpages of Subpages is SUBPAGE_PARENT_ID column in the SUBPAGE table. Using solution like this, I would have to iterate over whole table to get all children, I guess (or I miss something...).

Coming to the point: How do I have to implement this to get a Subpage class with possibility to get all children?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you have to iterate the entire table? You'd select on the parent id. The children are the same class-why would you need a separate table that holds identical data? That side, *you* don't have to do this manually, that's what gorm is for.

Comment: See this article on creating a tree structure. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880672/tree-structure-in-gorm-grails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken your Domain and modified a couple of things.  I omitted the compareTo method for brevity.  Note that `SortedSet subpageChild` is not needed.  It is already a SortedSet.  I also renamed it to `subpageChildren` because it should be plural.

```
class Subpage implements Comparable{

    String title
    Integer orderOfSubpage

    static hasMany = [component: Component, subpageChildren: Subpage]
    static belongsTo = [domain: Domain, subpageParent: Subpage]

    static constraints = {
        orderOfSubpage nullable:false;
        subpageParent nullable:true;
        subpageChild nullable:true;
    }
}
```

So let's take a look at some code:

```
def subpage = new Subpage(title: "Subpage 1", orderOfSubpage: 1)
def child1 = new Subpage(title: "Subpage child 1", orderOfSubpage: 1)
def child2 = new Subpage(title: "Subpage child 2", orderOfSubpage: 2)
subpage.addToSubpageChildren(child1)
subpage.addToSubpageChildren(child2)
subpage.save()
```

We've created a subpage with 2 children.  Now, let's see what a query looks like:

```
def subpage = Subpage.findByTitle("Subpage 1")
```

Now, let's iterate over its children

```
subpage.subpageChildren.each { child ->

}
```

That's basically it.  Only 1 table needed.

Comment: Another question to your code. Did you removed copareTo because it is not necessary or just to short the block code in comment? And if you removed just to short the code, do I even need to override this method?

Comment: I just removed it to keep it from being a distraction from the point I was trying to make.  You need it if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically creating a tree structure - there is already an answer on this here.

[Tree structure in GORM (grails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880672/tree-structure-in-gorm-grails)

Just as an aside I would just have a single "Page" domain class and use the naming subpage/subpages to reference the children.